# PANIC: unprotected error in call to Lua API (script1.lua:34: attempt to index global 'http' (a nil value))

Tags: lua, nodemcu

I get this error when trying to perform a HTTP GET request on my NodeMCU (using Lua programming language). It is connected via WiFi.

When the PIR sensor (Passive IR sensor) detects movement, the function `roepIFTTT()` gets called. The HTTP POST to IFTTT works well.

```
PANIC: unprotected error in call to Lua API (script1.lua:35: attempt to index global 'http' (a nil value))

 ets Jan  8 2013,rst cause:2, boot mode:(3,7)

load 0x40100000, len 26096, room 16 
tail 0
chksum 0x0c
load 0x3ffe8000, len 2232, room 8 
tail 0
chksum 0x7a
load 0x3ffe88b8, len 8, room 8 
tail 0
chksum 0x5f
csum 0x5f
ŒÂœäƒoä’sƒûo|ìld$l`„âr›lŒdŒŸ
```

That's the firmware:

```
NodeMCU custom build by frightanic.com
    branch: master
    commit: 7b83bbb2ea134cd85ac9d63108603cc02c4e20f7
    SSL: false
    modules: adc,bit,cjson,coap,dht,file,gpio,i2c,mqtt,net,node,ow,pwm,rtctime,sntp,spi,tmr,uart,wifi,ws2812
 build  built on: 2016-11-25 08:30
 powered by Lua 5.1.4 on SDK 1.5.4.1(39cb9a32)
```

---

Here is my code:

```
wifi.setmode(wifi.STATION)
wifi.sta.config("ssid", "password")
wifi.sta.connect()

ledpen = 0
gpio.mode(ledpen, gpio.OUTPUT)
gpio.write(ledpen, gpio.HIGH)

pirsensorpen = 2

gpio.mode(pirsensorpen, gpio.INT, gpio.PULLUP)

function beweging() -- This function gets called when movement is detected
    print("PIR sensor detecteerde beweging")
    gpio.write(ledpen, gpio.LOW)
    roepIFTTT(1)
    tmr.alarm(0, 2000, tmr.ALARM_SINGLE, function()
        gpio.write(ledpen, gpio.HIGH)
    end)
end

function roepIFTTT(value1)
  -- Trigger flashbutton op IFTTT
  conn = nil
  conn = net.createConnection(net.TCP, 0)
  conn:on("receive", function(conn, payload) end)
  conn:connect(80,"maker.ifttt.com")
  conn:on("connection", function(conn, payload)
  conn:send("POST /trigger/pirsensor/with/key/API_KEY?value1="..value1.." HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: maker.ifttt.com\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\nAccept: */*\r\n\r\n") end)
  conn:close()
  print("IFTTT is aangeroepen")



-- It is about the code below that generates the error. If there is another way if creating a simple HTTP GET request, it is welcome.
    http.get("http://httpbin.org/ip", nil, function(code, data)
    if (code < 0) then
      print("HTTP request failed")
    else
      print(code, data)
    end
  end)
  -- coe above


end

function metingNaarThingSpeak()  
  local a = adc.read(0)
  print("Value of moisture sensor: "..a)
  local conn = nil
  conn = net.createConnection(net.TCP, 0)
  conn:on("receive", function(conn, payload) end)
  conn:connect(80, "api.thingspeak.com")
  conn:on("connection", function(conn, payload)
  conn:send("GET /update?api_key=API_KEY&field1="..a.." HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: api.thingspeak.com\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\nAccept: */*\r\n\r\n") end)
  conn:close()
  print("Meting naar ThingSpeak verzonden")
end

gpio.trig(pirsensorpen, "up", beweging)
tmr.alarm(4, 60000, tmr.ALARM_AUTO, function() metingNaarThingSpeak() end)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Note: I am a complete newbie at this and I have never programmed in Lua, nor have I worked with a NodeMCU. I have other programming skills, so programming is no new thing to me.

Comment: provide more info on your code and your script files. the error indicates that the http library is not initialized.

Comment: FWIW. the language is called Lua, not LUA.   It's not an acronym.

Comment: @MarcBalmer I edited his post and fixed tags, format and "Lua"

Comment: @Marcel Sör: cool, thanks ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is right here

> modules: adc,bit,cjson,coap,dht,file,gpio,i2c,mqtt,net,node,ow,pwm,rtctime,sntp,spi,tmr,uart,wifi,ws2812

Your NodeMCU firmware is missing the HTTP module.